# Google Cloud Functions onFinalize() context

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

How can I pass some metadata along with an object when uploading it to a bucket?

I'm using a separate bucket for image manipulations, since I can't trigger Cloud Functions only within a specific folder inside my working ones, and thus I need to get that edited image back from that service bucket and place it then appropriately. Sounds very trivial but it turned out to be not.

That being said, I tried to get context by `.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {}`:

```
{ eventId: '226356658372982',
  timestamp: '2018-10-11T09:17:07.052Z',
  eventType: 'google.storage.object.finalize',
  resource: 
   { service: 'storage.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/_/buckets/bucket/objects/image.jpg',
     type: 'storage#object' },
  params: {} }
```

That wasn't very helpful though.
I can think of using `object.name` conditionals inside working buckets as a last resort but there should be a more civilized way to handle such situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your storage trigger to handle only certain files added to your bucket, you will have to write code in your function to determine if it's a file that you want to process.  This is commonly done by looking at the object's name, as you pointed out.

If you don't want to do that, you can attach metadata to a file at the time of upload.  Since you haven't said which language or environment you're using to upload the file, I'll point you to the node.js documentation for [upload()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#upload).  Note that there is a `metadata` property of the optional `options` argument.  Other platforms have a similar way of specifying metadata during upload.

The bottom line is that you will need to figure out in your function if you want to handle the file that's been finalized.

Comment: Huge! Already implemented `metadata` approach and even got long lasting url back by `getDownloadURL()`!